# Segmentation fault with pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
int main(){   
int j,rows,columns;
int i;
char **text;
char **final;

rows=45;
columns=7;


text=malloc(2*sizeof(char));

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
      text[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(char));


final=malloc(rows*sizeof(char));

for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            final[i]=malloc(columns*sizeof(char));
                      }

for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 for(j=0;j<3;j++)
      text[i][j]='a';

for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
 printf("i %d\n",i);
          for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
        printf("j %d\n",j);
                   final[i][j]='a';
          }
}

printf("%s\n%s\n",final[0],text[0]);


}
```

When I run it everything is fine with "text" pointer, but not with "final" pointer. A segmentation fault message appears when I try to initialize "final" with 'a'. Specifically the message is appeared when i=14 and j=0.Could someone tell me why?

Comment: With `text=malloc(2*sizeof(char))` you only allocate two bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines

```
final=malloc(rows*sizeof(char));
```

and

```
text=malloc(2*sizeof(char));
```

allocate space for `char`s. You need **pointers**, though, since `malloc` returns a **pointer**, which does not fit into a `char`.
Replace them by

```
final=malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
```

and

```
text=malloc(2*sizeof(char*));
```

---

Notes:

- If you didn't know: since `sizeof(char) == 1` by standard definition, you can omit the multiplications with `sizeof(char)`.